# How should I run periodical task in android

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, periodic-task

I'm writing application which need to periodically (around about 15min) download JSON data from server in the background and notify user with Notification.

I don't have a lot of experience with android coding and I'm asking how I should do that correctly and with best coding practises?

I don't need too much precision, AlarmManager with inexact repeating should work perfectly. I know how use BroadcastReceiver to receive BOOT_COMPLETE and start service. However I don't know how can I set AlarmManager to run specific action in Service and if I should do this in that way? I don't want use android mechanisms in way that has not been provided.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track already, try looking at https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services#using-with-alarmmanager-for-periodic-tasks

Comment: @hibob thank you a lot. That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask` for getting info from server. In onReceive method of Receiver class create new AsyncTask object and execute it as below:

```
private class GetContent extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> // Assume class name
extras = extras.getString("json");
GetContent().execute(extras);
```

In default function of AsyncTask `doInBackground`, retrive data and return `JSON`. In the other default function `onPostExecute`, create a `NotificationCompat.Builder` object and notify.

Answer (score 0):

Use the class TimerTask:

```
private TimerTask timerTask; 
private final long PERIOD_TIME=1000 * 60 * 15; //15min

@Override
public void onCreate() {

Timer timer = new Timer();

timerTask = new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Your request JSON
   }
  };

  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, PERIOD_TIME);
 }
```